# Grouping albums in iTunes

Tags: itunes

I just can't find a way to group albums, I have my albums in an external hard drive organized in folders like "albums from when I was back in high school" or "albums my dad recommended", that sort of thing. I don't like the albums I used to listen to in high school mixed with the ones I got yesterday. Is there a way to separate them in categories or something that gives them that sort of order?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be using playlists. You can drag folders of songs directly into an iTunes playlist. If the songs in question are already part of your library, doing this will create duplicates, so I'd recommend deleting theses songs from iTunes before adding them to your playlist.

Comment: but how is that gonna group albums? I mean for example 15 albums that I want to put aside as "albums I almost never listen to" and another 15 albums as "everyday albums". Are you saying i can create 2 separate playlists and each playlist will hold 15 albums?? If so, how do you do it please??

Comment: Yes, I think the best way to group your albums would be to create a separate playlist for each category you have. You can create a new playlist using the "plus" button in the bottom left corner of iTunes. You can then directly drag your folders into the playlist.

Answer (score 1):

Playlists are one way to do this. But you can also create custom genres, if you want. For example, select all the tracks of the "albums your dad recommended," press Command-I, and type in a custom genre in the Genre field, such as Dad's recommendations. You can then view these albums in Genres view easily. And you can build playlists using the genre as a condition.